# finding boundary elements in cartesian grid

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I have a 2D cartesian grid (see picture below). The colorful cells are filled element. I would like to detect blue cells. Blue cells are bound  elements if you scan from bottom to top and left to right and vice versa.

[image]

I wrote following code when I do scan from bottom, but I do not know what would be the best for all four side scanning. I try to simulate on the simple example below with 8 cells in x direction and 5 cells in y direction. However, the real problem is order of (10000 x 10000) cells. The following code only find the two bottom blue cells.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <set>

#include "iostream"

struct cell 
{
  cell(size_t i_x, size_t i_y)
    {
    x = i_x;
    y = i_y;
    }
  size_t x;
  size_t y;
  bool operator==(cell a)
    {
    if (a.x == x && a.y == y)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
    };
};



int main()
  {
  std::vector<cell> cartesian{ cell(0, 1), cell(0, 2), cell(0, 3),
    cell(1, 2), cell(1, 3), cell(1, 4), cell(1, 5), 
    cell(2, 1), cell(2, 2), cell(2, 3), cell(2, 4), cell(2, 5), 
    cell(3, 0), cell(3, 1), cell(3, 2), cell(3, 3), cell(3, 4), cell(3, 5), cell(3, 6), 
    cell(4, 2), cell(4, 3), cell(4, 4), cell(4, 5), cell(4, 6) };
  size_t max_X = 8;
  size_t max_Y = 5;


  std::vector<size_t> bound_elements;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < max_X; ++i)
    {
    bool found = false;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < max_Y; ++j)
      {
      auto is_filled = std::find(cartesian.begin(), cartesian.end(), cell(i, j));
      if (is_filled == cartesian.end())
        {
        continue;
        }
      size_t position = (j + (max_X* i));

      if (bound_elements.size() == 2)
        {
        bound_elements[1] = position;
        }
      else
        {
        bound_elements.push_back(position);
        }
      found = true;
      }
    if (found)
      {
      break;
      }
    }
  for (auto element : bound_elements)
    {
    std::cout  << element << std::endl;
    }
  return 0;
  }
```

For top to down It is just opposite side for loop iteration. This strategy seems to be too verbose, is there a better way in terms of performance or coding style?

Comment: Is that formatting of braces  on purpose?

Comment: @RaimundKrämer Looks a bit like [Whitesmiths indendation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Whitesmiths_style) but maybe it just got mangled.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You'll receive better reviews if you show a complete example.  For example, I recommend that you [edit] to show the necessary `#include` lines, and a `main()` that shows how to call your function.  It can really help reviewers if they are able to compile and run your program.

Comment: I edited as you said

Comment: My question is matter of algorithm more.

Comment: It's not clear how the elements of `cartesian` correspond to the diagram you've shown.  I eventually worked it out - row 0 is the bottom, not the top!  BTW, are the elements known to be in sorted order?

Comment: yes, they are in the sorted order and bottom is row zero. Sorry for being unclear

Comment: I'd written my answer before knowing that the sorted order is guaranteed - you may be able to adapt it to take advantage of that.

Comment: Not all rows and columns have a blue square. Is this intentional? Do I misunderstand that you want to find the first and last filled element for each row and each column?

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes, I do kind of scanning from four sides (top to bottom, bottom to top, left to right and right to left). Blue cells are the boundary of first row or column when I do scanning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Headers

I had to ditch the non-standard and missing `"stdafx.h"`, add `<algorithm>` and fix the spelling of `<iostream>` to compile this.

## Correct `std::size_t`

This type is consistently written as `size_t` without its namespace prefix, which is not portable.

## Cell type

`struct cell` could simply be a `std::pair`, but there may be benefit to stronger typing as you have it.  I recommend you prefer initialization of members rather than assignment (and that conveniently allows us to simply omit the constructor).  We can also change the `==` operator to take a reference and make it const (we could lean on `std::tuple` for the implementation, but it doesn't seem worth it for two members and only one operator).

```
struct cell
{
    const std::size_t x;
    const std::size_t y;

    bool operator==(const cell& a) const { return a.x == x && a.y == y; }
};
```

## Algorithm

Repeatedly searching for elements looks like a very time-consuming way of examining every cell.  Instead, we could just iterate over the known cells and update a set of minima and maxima for its row and column:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct cell
{
    const std::size_t x;
    const std::size_t y;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<cell> cartesian = {
        {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3},
        {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5},
        {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5},
        {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 6},
        {4, 2}, {4, 3}, {4, 4}, {4, 5}, {4, 6}
    };

    // map each row and column to (min,max) filled cell in that column
    std::map<std::size_t, std::pair<std::size_t,std::size_t>> row_range;
    std::map<std::size_t, std::pair<std::size_t,std::size_t>> column_range;

    for (const auto& c: cartesian) {
        auto rit = row_range.find(c.y);
        if (rit != row_range.end()) {
            auto& row = rit->second;
            if (c.x < row.first) {
                row.first = c.x;
            } else if (row.second < c.x) {
                row.second = c.x;
            }
        } else {
            row_range.insert({c.y, {c.x, c.x}});
        }

        auto cit = column_range.find(c.x);
        if (cit != column_range.end()) {
            auto& col = cit->second;
            if (c.y < col.first) {
                col.first = c.y;
            } else if (col.second < c.y) {
                col.second = c.y;
            }
        } else {
            column_range.insert({c.x, {c.y, c.y}});
        }
    }

    // show the results for column 0
    const auto zr = column_range[0];

    std::cout  << zr.first << ',' << zr.second << std::endl;
}
```

We can refactor the part that's common to rows and columns into a small helper method:

```
using range_map = std::map<std::size_t, std::pair<std::size_t,std::size_t>>;

static void update_min_max(range_map& ranges, std::size_t index,
                           std::size_t value)
{
    auto it = ranges.find(index);
    if (it != ranges.end()) {
        auto& range = it->second;
        if (value < range.first) {
            range.first = value;
        } else if (range.second < value) {
            range.second = value;
        }
    } else {
        ranges.insert({index, {value, value}});
    }
}
```

And then the loop becomes

```
    range_map row_range;
    range_map column_range;

    for (const auto& c: cartesian) {
        update_min_max(row_range, c.y, c.x);
        update_min_max(column_range, c.x, c.y);
    }
```

Comment: I've updated so that it compiles with `g++ -std=c++11` (and also my usual warnings: `-Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Weffc++`).

Comment: I would recomment to use `std::tie` for the comparison operator

Comment: @Is there a way to optimize your algorithm to the case that we do not need to fill the all rows and columns?  I do kind of scanning from four sides (top to bottom, bottom to top, left to right and right to left). Blue cells are the boundary of first row or column when I do scanning. There is a possibility to query if the cells is colorful.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking - do you mean that some rows and columns may be empty?  If so, those rows/columns won't appear as keys in the corresponding `range_map` variables.

Comment: @miscco, I considered that, but as I commented, it's longer and less clear for a single `==` operator with two members.

Comment: @TobySpeight This is true for `==` but the other operators are generally better served by std::tie if one doesnt need a special construct

Comment: Agreed - if the other relations were needed, I'd have definitely recommended a tuple, e.g. via `std::tie()`.